# How do I get rid of make_xxx() method?

Tags: python

I have 2 classes (e.g.)

```
class FilePath(Path):
    pass

class DirectoryPath(Path):
    pass
```

and I choose which one gets instantiated by a makepath() method, [simplified](https://github.com/jalanb/dotsite/blob/master/dotsite/paths.py#L427):

```
def makepath(string):
    if os.path.isfile(string):
        return FilePath(string)
    return DirectoryPath(string)
```

I haven't liked that make_xxx() method for years. It reminds me too much of a Java factory, so I was wondering if there was a more Pythonic idiom?

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call the design pattern a "Java factory". It's a language-agnostic concept, and it was popular in Smalltalk-80 for 15 years before Java was even invented. Feel free to use factories in whatever language you like :-)

Comment: A factory is a factory, however you implement it - and as Kevin mentions, there's nothing Java-specific in the factory pattern. A plain function is the obvious, simple, default implementation in Python, and unless your real logic requires a more complex construct it's the most pythonic one.

Comment: Thanks for the recipe below Bruno. Agree that my simplified method is actually more Pythonic. Time to lose a bit of baggage, methinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other solutions (like overriding `Path.__new__`) but

1. it's still a factory and
2. chances are it will be more complicated for no good reason, which by itself is enough to make it unpythonic.

For illustration purpose, here's a Q&D example using `abc` to find the appropriate concrete subclass without harcoding child classes in the base class:

```
import os
import abc

class Path(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __new__(cls, path):       
        imp = cls._get_subclass_for(path)
        instance = super(Path, cls).__new__(imp)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    @classmethod
    def _get_subclass_for(cls, path):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
            if subclass.match(path):
                return subclass
        raise LookupError("No matching subclass for path '%s'" % path)

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def match(path):
        return False


@Path.register
class FilePath(Path):
    @staticmethod
    def match(path):
        return os.path.isfile(path)


@Path.register
class DirectoryPath(Path):
    @staticmethod
    def match(path):
        return os.path.isdir(path)
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case just "`path`" sounds nice.
Since makepath method returns or directory or file path, just path seems like more general and short!

```
def path(string):
    if os.path.isfile(string):
        return FilePath(string)
    return DirectoryPath(string)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for a new name for his function. I think he wants to replace the function with something else entirely. A factory is a factory, even if it doesn't have "make" in its name.